# Errir with missing module

Tags: node.js, npm, discord, node-modules, discord.js

I have bot in Discord Bot Maker. Its working perfectly on my pc (Windows 10), but when I move it to my VPS (Ubuntu 16.04) and try to start it using node bot.js, I will get error with missing module.

Error:

```
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './constants'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/justwolf/butter/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:19:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

bot.js: https://hastebin.com/koredupoka.js

Comment: Post relevant code from `bot.js`. It's not easy to figure out what your problem is with just the error message.

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error :

```
Error: Cannot find module './constants'
```

means that somewhere in your code you have

```
.... = require('./constants')
```

but the file `constants.js` doesn't exist or at least not where it's supposed to be. Maybe when you uploaded your bot script to your VPS you forgot to upload that file.

Sometimes, in ready-made scripts, configuration variables such as database credentials and stuff are stored in a file named `constants.js` and this file is not versionned (it has en entry in `.gitignore`). Maybe you have a file named `constants.js.dist` or `constants.js.example`. It means you need to edit it and rename it to `constants.js`

Comment: Thats problem. I opened bot.js and there is nothing with constants also its not my bot. My friend sent it to me and I will only provide hosting for him.. so he sent me full folder with bot.

Comment: try to use `grep` or `ag` to look for occurences of the word "constants" in your entire code because there is one. That's what the error means.

Comment: I tried grep "constants" bot.js and nothing happened. I also tried to find "constants" in Atom editor.

Comment: use it on the entire folder. Go to your project folder and run `grep -inr constants ./`

Comment: Yeah.. I did this too.. now Iam waiting before it will end searching.

Comment: use `ag` maybe, it's faster. `sudo apt install silversearcher-ag` then `ag constants`

Comment: Okay.. fixed.. Idk where was problem, but it worked when I downloaded bot from friend to pc, ran it and then moved to VPS. Anyway.. thanks for helping.

Comment: Okay.. Its not fixed.. I used ag, as you suggested to me. I know now, where is problem. ./constants is in pngjs package. Is tehe any way, how to fix thet without removing this package? (needed for jimp package). I trie to delete it and install it.. still same problem with missing ./constants.

Comment: sounds weird. Try to manually put the file in `node_modules/pngjs/lib/ `
You can find it here : https://github.com/lukeapage/pngjs/blob/master/lib/constants.js

Comment: I have fixed it yesterday. Something was wrong on friend's side. constants dissapeard when hi zipped it. When he sent me raw data of all commands, I added it to my bot in DBM, uploaded it to VPS and everything working.